InaccessibleObjectException when creating cache with Redisson
I'm trying to get Redisson set up to use for bucket4j with my spring boot 2.7.3 application running on JVM 17. For now, I'm using a unit test to get everything working at some reasonable level but obviously will need a for real implementation later.
On to the code...
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class Bucket4JConfig {
    public static final String CACHE_NAME = "r_quota_";

    @Bean
    public Config envConfig() {
        var port = "6379";
        var host = "localhost";
        BinaryOperator<String> getUrl = (h, p) -> String.format("redis://%s:%s", h, p);
        Config config = new Config();
        config.useReplicatedServers()
                .setReadMode(ReadMode.SLAVE)
                .addNodeAddress(getUrl.apply(host, port));
        return config;
    }

    @Bean(name = "javaxCacheManager")
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public ProxyManager<String> proxyManager(CacheManager cacheManager, Config config) {
        Cache<String, byte[]> cache = cacheManager.getCache(CACHE_NAME);
        if (cache == null) {
            MutableConfiguration<String, byte[]> jcacheConfig = new MutableConfiguration<>();
            jcacheConfig.setExpiryPolicyFactory(null); // never expire
            javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<String, byte[]> redissonConfiguration = RedissonConfiguration.fromConfig(config, jcacheConfig);
            cache = cacheManager.createCache(CACHE_NAME, redissonConfiguration);
        }
        return new JCacheProxyManager<>(cache);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public SyncCacheResolver bucket4jCacheResolver(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        return new JCacheCacheResolver(cacheManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public JCacheManagerCustomizer jCacheManagerCustomizer(Config config) {
        return cacheManager -> cacheManager.createCache(CACHE_NAME, RedissonConfiguration.fromConfig(config));
    }
}

@Service
public class RateLimitService {

    private static final int QUOTA = 2;
    private final ProxyManager<String> buckets;

    public RateLimitService(ProxyManager<String> buckets) {
        this.buckets = buckets;
    }

    public void blockOnBucket(String bucketName) throws InterruptedException {
        resolveBucket(bucketName).asBlocking().consume(1);
    }

    private Bucket resolveBucket(String bucketName) {
        Supplier<BucketConfiguration> confSupplier = () -> {
            return BucketConfiguration.builder()
                    .addLimit(limit -> limit.capacity(QUOTA).refillGreedy(QUOTA, Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
                    .build();
        };
        return buckets.builder().build(bucketName, confSupplier);
    }
}

public class Bucket4JOverRedissonTest {

    private RateLimitService rateLimitService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        Bucket4JConfig conf = new Bucket4JConfig();
        var config = conf.envConfig();
        var cacheManager = conf.cacheManager();
        System.out.printf("Caches: [%s]", Streams.stream(cacheManager.getCacheNames()).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
        rateLimitService = new RateLimitService(conf.proxyManager(cacheManager, config));
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        String bucketName = "LIMITED_RESOURCE";
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.start();;
        rateLimitService.blockOnBucket(bucketName);
        rateLimitService.blockOnBucket(bucketName);
        rateLimitService.blockOnBucket(bucketName);
        stopWatch.stop();

        Assertions.assertTrue(stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis() > 1000);

    }
}

I added these lines to my pom.xml:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bucket4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>bucket4j_jdk17-redis-common</artifactId>
            <version>8.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bucket4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>bucket4j_jdk17-redisson</artifactId>
            <version>8.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.giffing.bucket4j.spring.boot.starter</groupId>
            <artifactId>bucket4j-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>

And I continuously get the exception:
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final byte[] java.lang.String.value accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @1d371b2d

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTClazzInfo.createFieldInfo(FSTClazzInfo.java:504)
    at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTClazzInfo.createFields(FSTClazzInfo.java:367)
    at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTClazzInfo.<init>(FSTClazzInfo.java:128)
    at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTClazzInfoRegistry.getCLInfo(FSTClazzInfoRegistry.java:129)
    at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTClazzNameRegistry.addClassMapping(FSTClazzNameRegistry.java:97)
    at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTClazzNameRegistry.registerClassNoLookup(FSTClazzNameRegistry.java:84)
    at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTClazzNameRegistry.registerClass(FSTClazzNameRegistry.java:80)
    at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTConfiguration.addDefaultClazzes(FSTConfiguration.java:811)
    at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTConfiguration.initDefaultFstConfigurationInternal(FSTConfiguration.java:478)
    at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTConfiguration.createDefaultConfiguration(FSTConfiguration.java:473)
    at org.nustaq.serialization.FSTConfiguration.createDefaultConfiguration(FSTConfiguration.java:465)
    at org.redisson.codec.FstCodec.<init>(FstCodec.java:47)
    at org.redisson.config.Config.<init>(Config.java:104)
    at org.redisson.Redisson.<init>(Redisson.java:119)
    at org.redisson.Redisson.create(Redisson.java:164)
    at org.redisson.jcache.JCacheManager.createCache(JCacheManager.java:125)
    at io.pacaso.insights.api.config.Bucket4JConfig.proxyManager(Bucket4JConfig.java:50)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

The issue is related to your java environment not having access to specified module due to an update in JDK17. You'll need to add --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED to your environment's arguments depending on your specific setup.

Yeah so that was it. I'm not going to be able to deploy to production with that option. I upgraded redisson-spring-boot-starter and the error went away. Unfortunately, I don't think that will be compatible with my version of Spring but we'll see.

Per @tangy (from a comment):

The issue is related to your java environment not having access to
specified module due to an update in JDK17. You'll need to add
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED to your environment's arguments depending on your specific setup.

